# Using a NCHW trained GAN on PC with CPU only?

Tags: tensorflow

I am playing around with [Progressive Growing of Gans](https://github.com/tkarras/progressive_growing_of_gans) network from Karras et al. (NVIDIA). I trained the network on a different dataset on 2x 1080 Ti cards, using the NCHW mode for all convolutions [as seen here](https://github.com/tkarras/progressive_growing_of_gans/blob/master/networks.py#L93).

Now I have a trained model and I want to use the code snippet from the project's readme to [import the trained network](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1A79qKDTFp6pExe4gTSgBsEOkxwa2oes_) - which is mentioned in the *Importing and using pre-trained networks* section.

However, when I try to run it on a PC with a CPU only, the network fails with the error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Conv2DCustomBackpropInputOp only supports NHWC.
         [[node Gs/Run/Gs/cond/8x8/Conv0_up/conv2d_transpose (defined at <string>:93) ]]
```

I know that the CPU does not have NCHW implemented, but I would like to know how can I work around this? I see several options out of which I do not want any:

- The first thing that comes to mind is to **just use the NHWC mode for generating a new image**, even though the network was trained in NCHW. This, however, if I am correct, will mess up the layer's weights, since it was trained on NCHW.
- I do not want to train the whole network in NHWC mode, since it should be slower than NCHW? I do not use the cuDNN from NVidia, does it mean that those two modes are the same speed then, [according to this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/overview#data_formats)?

What else can I do? Thank you!

Comment: Same problem here, i think it is a TF flaw. Mixing gpu and cpu based tensors may broke the pipeline. I use a GAN in dataset.map function and get this error due to the behaviour of the dataset.map forces execution in cpu, but some of the graph parts are placed on the gpu. This is a theory though, i don't know the root of the problem yet.